# Matching type constraints in Scala fails

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a map wrapper in Scala 2.9.2 with values that have a particular higher kinded type, and am wrestling with the type system. Here is a cut down version of the code to illustrate the problem:

```
trait A

trait B[C] {
  def c: C
}

trait E[C <: B[C], D <: A]

case class MyMap[M <: A, L <: B[L], N[L, M]](map: Map[M, N[L, M]])

object MyMap {
  def empty[M <: A, L <: B[L], N[L, M]] = MyMap(Map.empty[M, N[L, M]])
}

val myMap = MyMap.empty[A, T forSome { type T <: B[T] }, E]
```

when I try and compile this, the last statement fails with a compiler error, indicating that I am not matching type bounds. However to me it looks like I am, and perhaps that where I have N[L, M] and previously L <: B[L], it is not inferring that the L in N[L, M] is the same L <: B[L], and likewise for M. Error is as follows:

> kinds of the type arguments (A,T forSome { type T <: B[T] },E) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type M,type L,type N). E's type parameters do not match type N's expected parameters: type C's bounds >: Nothing <: B[C] are stricter than type L's declared bounds >: Nothing <: Any, type D's bounds >: Nothing <: A are stricter than type M's declared bounds >: Nothing <: Any
>
> val myMap = MyMap.empty[A, T forSome { type T <: B[T] }, E]

Any advice gratefully received.

Thanks -

Answer (score 2):

There is one problem with the second parameter and one with the third. I don't know about the second parameter, I'm not sure what may be allowed here with existentia. So this is just about the problem with the third parameter.

A bit of simpler code with the same error :

```
class A {}

class C[X <: A] {}

def f[X[_]] = 12

f[List]
res1: Int12
f[C]
error: kinds of the type arguments (C) do not conform to 
the expected kinds of the type parameters (type X).
C's type parameters do not match type X's expected parameters: 
    type X's bounds >: Nothing <: A are stricter 
    than type _'s declared bounds >: Nothing < : Any
       f[C]
         ^
```

Quite simply, method empty expects as third type parameter a generic type with two parameters *and no restrictions*. In the body of empty, you are allowed to write `N[Int, String]` or whatever. Type `E`, which has some constraints, is not compatible with this (note: I find `writing N[L,M`] rather than `N[_, _]`, with `L` and `M` the name of the previous type parameters a bit misleading. Or maybe it suggests you don't really want a higher order type parameter).

If you write in the code above

```
def g[X[_ <: A]] = 13
```

then calling `g[C]` is ok  (`g[List]` ok too, as it should, nothing wrong can happen there).

Similarly, your code would work (provided you pass a suitable second parameter) if empty was

```
Map.empty[M <: A, L <: B[L], N[X <: B[X], Y <: A]]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Using your example, and my trait B, if C was defined as `class C[X <: B[X]] {}`, how would you then define the function g?

Comment: def g[X[Y <: B[Y]] (just as the empty on the last line, N[X <: B[X]...])

Comment: thanks. So what if I wanted say a list of these Cs, with no further constraints than already on C (I think this is the real problem I have once we strip it down). I've tried `val l = List[C[T forSome { type T <: B[T] } ]()` which complains with "type arguments [T forSome { type T <: B[T] }] do not conform to class C's type parameter bounds [X <: B[X]]"